# How can I make my MacBook Air show the file info the way the old macOS does?

Tags: macos, finder, metadata

My old MacBook Pro running macOS 10.13.6 gives all the info I care about in the Finder when I select the file in interest, pointed out by the red rectangle.

[image]

My new M1 MacBook Air running macOS 13 doesn't do the job well. I have to resize the window, so that I can see the dimensions info.

How can I make my MacBook Air show the file info the same way that the older macOS does?

[image]

#### Preview options.

I can set preview options for a particular image, though it affects just the one I selected.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the option to view the window as Gallery?

Comment: @ErniePC12 that's a working alternative. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set what is shown in the preview pane in the Preview Options, under the View menu.

[image]

Beyond that, you'll just have to set your default Finder window to be large enough to show what you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply. as i said in 'Preview options' section, it affects just the one I selected.

Comment: @JJJohn It's usually possible to set the defaults. Try closing all but one window, set the options, then close that window, and see if new windows respect the settings.

Comment: i tried. it doesn't work.